# insetting multiple faces with continuous borders

Tags: modeling

My question is associated with insetting faces on a mesh which is undivided by continuous borders.

In the example outlined with red rectangle the mesh I have selected the faces and did an inset, and it insets 3 faces as one. But on the bottom section I'm trying to do the same, but the faces don't have a gap between them. So I select the faces, and do the inset, but the inset either makes a border around all the faces, or each face becomes a square. How can I make the inset with the faces selected which don't have gaps, and get a continuous inset like in the example in red rectangle.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure you can do that, you'll need to do it 3 at a time

Comment: Moonboots is right. Just select 5 areas of 3 faces and inset them. Blender doesn't know where you want the gaps :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to split insets to order, but carry them all out at the same time as a way of keeping them even, you can isolate islands by <kbd>V</kbd> temporarily ripping an edge-selection...

[image]

.. followed by <kbd>M</kbd> > 'By Distance' merging your split edges back together again

Comment: This is what I had figured out too after so many tutorials I gained more knowledge using Blender. It would be so great if there was a feature just to be able to select the edges which alerts Blender that they are isolated from one another. But maybe in the near future the developers will come up with something.

Kind regards.

Comment: @blenderbreath    My 2c on that.. be careful what features you wish for :). I wouldn't want Blender to become a nightmare forest of tiny-button-options like, say, 3DS. I would rather be handed a minimal selection of tools, and be expected to learn how to use them. I wonder what better tag there would be for: 'consider me a boundary' than : 'I _am_ a boundary (reversibly)'.. maybe 'Mark Sharp'? ..but the grammar should be consistent. I _do_ wish Vertex Weights were more tightly integrated into the editing UI, and the notion of 'Edge  Weights' was more general than simply applying to bevels.

Answer (score 1):

Press the <kbd>i</kbd> key while the inset tool is currently active. It stands for "individual," and can be toggled to switch back and forth between scaling the newly insetted face centered on the old one, versus scaling it while connected to at least one edge. You can also look at the top of your viewport while the tool is active to see which of these two modes the "individual" feature is in currently.

Comment: Hey there, when I press the <kbd>i</kbd> that's whats happening, its making it into smaller divided up tiles, or just scales them all together with a border.